# SQL QUERY SQL SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi can anyone help me with sum up first two rows in table and then rest would be same. example is

```
ID SUM
12 60
0  20
1  30
2  50 
3  60
```

I am expecting

```
ID SUM
0  80
1  30
2  50
3  60
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first two rows" in a table. Rows in a relational table have **no** sort order unless you can define an `order by` that defines that order - but I can't find any column in your output that would define the "first two rows" as you seem to expect them. So which column should be used to order the result so that you get a _defined_ sort order?

Comment: what dictates the order of that table?

Comment: May be I can add another ID column like this "ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY" in this temp table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing this from memory - so if this doesnt work let me know and we can do it another way looking at the row number;

Assuming you have a unique ID to sort it by as you suggested, you could do something like this;

you may want to change the order to be desc if that's how you classify your 'top 2'

```
SELECT  TOP 2 ID,
        SUM(VALUE)
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID 

UNION 

SELECT  ID, 
        VALUE
FROM [Table]
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 2 ID 
                 FROM [Table] ORDER BY ID)
```

Comment: Thanks James I did bit of modification on this. And it works for me